# Variable Importance - what to do with values?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm finding it difficult to interpret Variable Importance scores from my dataset. What is the relevance of knowing the Variable Importance of features in your dataset? Is it just for information so that you will better understand the dataset? Or should some action be taken with the information?

For example, if I have 3 variables with very high Variable Importance scores, and 12 variables with much lower Variable Importance scores, should I now remove some of the "less important" features to improve my prediction accuracy? Or is this just viewed as information that can be used in future decisions related to that dataset?

Comment: I believe you are getting downvotes because you have not specified your algorithmic approach that is producing variable importances.

Comment: What is a "variable importance score"?

Answer (score 1):

The main use of variable importance, at least for me, is to diagnose problems with the data. For instance, if one variable is by far the most predictive, it is quite likely that "label leakage" is occurring, where inadvertently information contained in the label also appears in that feature. It sounds silly, but when you have thousands of features this often happens accidently. It's important to understand why that feature might be so predictive, before going foward.

I would not remove features that have low importance, although I come from a machine learning background. Feature pruning is more common in statistical circles.

Variable importance is also useful to convince others that your sophisticated ML/stats algorithm is doing something reasonable. It reveals some of the inner workings of an otherwise blackbox model.

Comment: The statistically inclined users here would generally agree with you on variable pruning.